# First charector of EditText should be alphabet

Tags: android, textwatcher

In my `EditText` I want to enter the first character as alpha and the remaining is whatever. I achieved this task with the help of `TextWatcher`. But now my problem is if I entered something wrong(like digits, special characters) as my First character then my `EditText` shouldn't accept the remaining characters. If I correct my first character then only my `EditText` should accept. Is their any possibility to achieve this friends? If yes then please guide me friends.

My textWatcher code is

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            String str = edittext.getText().toString();
            char t = str.charAt(0);
            if (!Character.isLetter(t)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "please enter your first charecter as alpha",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a better description of your problem.  What does it mean "*in table itself*"?  Are you asking about `SELECT` query to find duplicates?

Comment: What is the desired output that you are looking for? Do you want to select those that has duplicates, or those that has unique?

Comment: @praveen your Query will work for only one Column of value...For Ex: i want to insert more than one Developer in Department But Could not allow More than One Head/Department....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON UnnamedTable (Department) WHERE Designation='Head'
```

It's called a [Filtered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188783.aspx). If you're on a pre-2008 version of SQL Server, you can implement a poor-mans equivalent of a filtered index using an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW UnnamedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT Department From UnnamedSchema.UnnamedTable WHERE Designation='Head'
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON UnnamedView (Department)
```

Comment: So that would allow duplicate values in Designation for all values except `"Head"`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - it allows duplicates of the combination of (Department,Designation), provided Designation is not `Head`. Where Designation is `Head`, each (Department,Designation) pair may only appear once.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know something like this is possible. +1

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - the cheeky thing about this answer is it's a virtual copy & paste of another answer I've already given today - except for some minor column renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following query to view duplicates:

```
Select Department,Designation,count(*) 
From [mytable] Group by Department,Designation
```

Now replace mytable with the table name and department and designation with the columns in the table. After execution the result set will show a count of more than one for duplicate records.